# Is instantiating WP_Query not possible within an admin Ajax call?

Tags: wp-query, ajax, admin

While using the WordPress Ajax API to query certain posts the content of WP_Query is always empty (that means the class exists but ***every property is set to null or false***).

```
function my_ajax_admin() {
        $query = new WP_Query();
        $tab = array();


        while($query->have_posts()):
            // never reached
        endwhile;
        die(json_encode($out));
    }
}
```

Is it in general not possible to use `WP_Query` in Ajax called? May I load something into the function to make it work? Do I require additional parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the constructor of `WP_Query` [is](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f1be128cde8f743a3c7563ceacf496a01e1cbce8/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L3355):

```
public function __construct( $query = '' ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query ) ) {
        $this->query( $query );
    }
}
```

so you need a non-empty query input in your current code snippet.

Here's a simple test example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'post' ] );
wp_send_json_success( $query->posts );
```

but you can check out e.g. [`wp_ajax_query_attachments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_query_attachments/) to see how WordPress uses `WP_Query` in an ajax call.

Also check out the built-in [Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), it might already have the query you're looking for?